# Fin airfoil holder design and technical drawings not understood

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks, technical-drawing, rocketry, airfoils

I am trying to draw a fin for my final year project, but I could not fully understand the technical drawing explanations that I marked with red markings.

especially R1.281 DEFINES TANGENCY OF R1.312 WITH FIN SURFACE, I couldn't understand the part.
My goal is to make a "bubble fin holder" like in the last picture.
I'm also wondering how we can draw this part of fin .
high resolution image is here
https://i.imgur.com/OmEKV7J.jpeg
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image],

[image]

https://i.imgur.com/OmEKV7J.jpeg

Comment: Would be better if you could give higher res picture of the drawing. Its hard to read so your less likely to get answers. Anyway the shae has a 1.312 round

Comment: @joojaa yeap ı add it as a link,I didn't notice that, thanks for the warning https://i.imgur.com/OmEKV7J.jpeg

Comment: Are you asking two questions? 1. What does the original drawing mean? 2. How do I draw the item in the photograph?

Comment: @Transistor yeap, thats right Im asking two question.My major is electronics, but I know a bit of technical drawing, frankly I didn't understand exactly what drawing meant. The next step is drawing.I was only able to achieve a certain part of the drawing.Solidworks screenshots are mine.

Comment: I have successfully drawn the leading edge and trailing edge parts of the drawing, but I could not fully understand and draw the part that looks like a buuble, which I marked in "red".

Comment: I can't make sense of the original drawing. The cylindrical base part seems to be missing some detail lines in one or other of the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the rightmost view of the drawing that the R1.32 does not meet a spherical surface as suggested by Transistor, but in fact meets the vertical extension of the cylindrical surface beneath.

[image: Difference between]

The Quickest way to get closer to the drawn geometry (likely within the generous tolerance banding) is to use "Delete and Patch" to simply remove the dome face after you have applied the fillet

[image: Delete Face]

Comment: thank you very much @JonathanRSwift  i think this is the most realistic approach. https://i.imgur.com/tr2hZKk.png   but I still don't know how to draw. I need to extrude from 0.65mm base and apply fillet. So what kind of fillet did you apply here?

Comment: You don't need to start again - just delete this face https://i.imgur.com/52FcNjf.png from your existing model using the delete and patch option as shown! (Roll back to before the hole in the history tree, though)

Comment: Now I understand, I am truly grateful to you. Thanks thanks thanks.

Comment: I would like to express your support for me in my article. If you want, please contact me.

Comment: Hi - there's no need to worry about this - just credit "Jonathan R Swift on StackExchange" if you really want!

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I can't make much sense of the original drawing.

Regarding the fin photo, it's not clear from the single photo if the bulbous area is spherical or not. If so then a revolve and fillet might suffice.

[image]

[image]

Drawings done using [OnShape](https://onshape.com).

Comment: thanks your effort , thats great

Comment: I forgot to mention that I drew the sketch for the bulge referenced to the right plane which is the centre of the part. i.e. The top of the spherical part is in the middle of the fin.

Comment: Do you have a e-mail?I want to show results.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to communicate through SE.

Comment: @electronx - this is incorrect! - I'm just modelling it up myself now, but this does not match the very right hand view

Comment: hey jonathan just check out my post, i need different opinions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
[image]

I took the radius of the sphere and added a fillet of 1.312, here is the result